# Create new controller with new action in Sylius

Tags: symfony, sylius

We are trying to extend Resource Contoller and create our CertificateController which is new module.

```
class CertificateController extends ResourceController
{
    /**
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request): Response
    {
        echo "cert list";die;
    }
```

Routing.yml:

```
admin_api_certificate_index:
    path: /
    methods: [GET]
    defaults:
        _controller: sylius.controller.certificate:indexAction
        _sylius:
            serialization_version: $version
            serialization_groups: [Default]
            paginate: $limit
            sortable: true
            sorting:
                id: desc
```

I'm getting error like:

```
{
"code": 500,
"message": "Controller not found: service "sylius.controller.certificate" does not exist."
}
```

If I define service:

```
sylius.controller.certificate:
        class: Goldco\Controller\Api\CertificateController
```

getting error like:

```
{
"code": 500,
"message": "Type error: Too few arguments to function Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Controller\ResourceController::__construct(), 0 passed in E:\GoldCo_PHP\var\cache\dev\Container4rqmf99\getSylius_Controller_CertificateService.php on line 8 and exactly 17 expected"
}
```

Any arguements needs to pass here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your `Certificate` as a sylius resource so that the resource bundle compiler pass is aware of it and creates the appropiate services:

```
sylius_resource:
  resources:
    app.certificate:
        classes:
            model: Full\Certificate\Class\Path\Here
            controller: Goldco\Controller\Api\CertificateController
```